# Add module name to a list and iterate over it

Tags: python-3.x, python-module

I have numerous modules that I need to iterate over. When I create a list of the module names and try to iterate over them, Python treats the module names as strings, and complains that the string does not have an attribute. For instance:

```
import mod1
import mod2

mod_names_list = ['mod1', 'mod2']

for mod in mod_names_list:
  mod.some_method()
```

The above gives an error "ttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'some_method'.

However, the below works fine:

```
import mod1
import mod2


mod1.some_method()
mod2.some_method()
```

Comment: You're just iterating over a list of strings in the first example. If you need to make this list, why not make a list of module objects instead `mod_list = [mod1, mod2]; for mod in mod_list:`?

Comment: Oh right, I forgot I had single quotes in the list of module names, which made it a list of strings. Thanks! I removed the single quotes and it works now. Appreciate your help.